# GitAhead disable HTTPS Login Window

Tags: gitahead

Each 4 minutes GitAhead opens a small window for asking HTTPS Login/Password.

How I can say : Please do not disturb me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off automatic fetch from Tools -> Options... -> General -> Automatic Actions -> Fetch every xx minutes.